# Why a named function declaration isn't hoisted if you put it inside the return statement?

Tags: javascript

is putting the function declaration beside the return statement causing the function not to hoist?
or putting it inside the return statement turns it into a function expression that's why it isn't hoisted?

```js
// Hoisting doesn't work in here
function outer() {
  console.log(inner); // Isn't hoisted
  return function inner() {
    console.log("hello world");
  };
}
outer();
```

```js
// Works in here
function outer() {
  console.log(inner);

  function inner() {
    console.log("hello world");
  }
  return inner;
}
outer();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function hoisting and the return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405327/function-hoisting-and-the-return-statement)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put a `function` immediately after the `return` keyword, it's no longer a function declaration; `return` can only have an *expression* to the right of it, so it's interpretered as a function expression, and function expressions aren't hoisted (or have their name put into the surrounding scope as a variable).

This isn't something particular to `return`. Any other keyword that forces the `function` part to be interpreted as an expression will have the same effect:

```js
function outer() {
  console.log(typeof inner); // Isn't hoisted
  if (function inner() {
    console.log("hello world");
  }) {
  }
}
outer();
```

```js
function outer() {
  console.log(typeof inner); // Isn't hoisted
  switch (function inner() { console.log("hello world"); }) {
  
  }
}
outer();
```

```js
function outer() {
  console.log(typeof inner); // Isn't hoisted
  const x = function inner() {
    console.log("hello world");
  };
}
outer();
```

For a function to be interpreted as a function declaration (and function declarations are the only functions which get hoisted), the `function` must be a standalone statement, not directly connected to any other statements in the code via operators or keywords.